# Displaying a date on a TFT without using an array of numbers in char form

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to write the day of a month to a TFT display from a `DateTime` instance. The data for the `DateTime` instance is coming from an RTC.

Basically, I am trying to do this:

```cpp
DateTime timenow;
timenow = rtc.now();                      // Get and store the current RTC data as DateTime.
tft.textWrite(timenow.day());             // This doesn't work (see below), but it shows the idea of what I am trying to do.
```

`tft.textWrite` accepts a `char` as its parameter, but `timenow.day()` appears to output an `int`. The only way I have been able to get it to work (*which is obviously not a good way, as you will see*) is by making an enormous array with all of the numbers from 1 to 31 as a `char`:

```cpp
const char days[31][3] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"};
```

Then I used the array in my code:

```cpp
DateTime timenow;
timenow = rtc.now();                      // Get and store the current RTC data as DateTime.
tft.textWrite(days[timenow.day() - 1]);
```

Unfortunately, I have to do the same thing for the year, and I can't manually type in all of the years in the forseeable future into an array. It would take up memory and, besides, would be unnecessarily time-consuming.

**My question is, can someone tell me how I can convert from an `int` to a `char` for use in this function without the need for the huge array?**

I have tried everything from `String(timenow.day())` to `char(timenow.day())` to things like `char(String(timenow.day()))` and none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the integer into a string.

```c
    int day = timenow.day();
    char str[12];
    sprintf(str, "%d", day);
    tft.textWrite(str);
```

**EDIT:**

Code explanation:

- First, we store the integer value of the `timenow.day()` into `day`;
- Then we declare a `char` array to store the conversion of the `int day` into `char. It will be used in the`sprintf()`function call. This char array must be big enough to hold the conversion string. So that is why I used`char str[12]` here. So, we have 12 bytes to store the converted value.
- The `sprintf(str, "%d", day)` takes a `char *` as its first argument where the conversion will be stored. The second argument is the format of the output string you want to get. Then, the next arguments are those required by the format string you passed, in this case, it is the `"%d"`, which means we need to give an integer value to it. That is why we are passing the `day` variable as the last argument.

You can get more details in `sprintf` capabilities by running `man sprintf` in your Linux terminal. Otherwise, you can get more info [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c++11 you can use to_string something like this:
   tft.textWrite(std::to_string(timenow.day()).c_str())